# Can split and array work together?

Tags: equations, arrays, multline

I have the following problem. I need an equation which contains arrays and which should be on different lines because too long for one line.

This is the code:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
-\frac{r_{uv}^\perp\left(r_{uv}^\perp\right)^T}{||p_v-p_u||}T(\Psi_u)^T=\\
&
\frac{\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
r_{uv_y}^2 & -r_{uv_x}r_{uv_y}\\
-r_{uv_x}r_{uv_y} & r_{uv_x}^2
\end{array}
\right]}{||p_v-p_u||}
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
\cos(\Psi_u) & \sin(\Psi_u)\\
-\sin(\Psi_u)  &  \cos(\Psi_u) 
\end{array}
\right]
= 
&
\begin{array}{cc}
-r_{uv_y}^2c_{\Psi_u}-r_{uv_x}r_{uv_y}s_{\Psi_u} & r_{uv_y}^2s_{\Psi_u}+r_{uv_x}r_{uv_y}c_{\Psi_u}\\
r_{uv_x}r_{uv_y}c_{\Psi_u}+r_{uv_x}^2s_{\Psi_u} & r_{uv_x}r_{uv_y}s_{\Psi_u}-r_{uv_x}^2c_{\Psi_u}
\end{array}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

The error I get is the following:

```
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<template> }$\hfill \endtemplate
l.753 \end{split}
You have given more \span or & marks than there were
in the preamble to the \halign or \valign now in progress.
So I'll assume that you meant to type \cr instead.
```

I think the error comes from the thing that for the array I need a `\\` character and inside a `\split` envitonment it can't work.

Can you help me with this?
Thanks a lot.

**EDIT:**

My hardcoded solution for now is the following. But I know it is not the best. I created an equation* (`\begin{equation*}`) which is without reference number and another one with the reference number (`\begin{equation}`).

```
\begin{equation*}
-\frac{r_{uv}^\perp\left(r_{uv}^\perp\right)^T}{||p_v-p_u||}T(\Psi_u)^T=
\frac{\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
r_{uv_y}^2 & -r_{uv_x}r_{uv_y}\\
-r_{uv_x}r_{uv_y} & r_{uv_x}^2
\end{array}
\right]}{||p_v-p_u||}
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
\cos(\Psi_u) & \sin(\Psi_u)\\
-\sin(\Psi_u)  &  \cos(\Psi_u) 
\end{array}
\right]
= 
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation}
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
-r_{uv_y}^2c_{\Psi_u}-r_{uv_x}r_{uv_y}s_{\Psi_u} & r_{uv_y}^2s_{\Psi_u}+r_{uv_x}r_{uv_y}c_{\Psi_u}\\
r_{uv_x}r_{uv_y}c_{\Psi_u}+r_{uv_x}^2s_{\Psi_u} & r_{uv_x}r_{uv_y}s_{\Psi_u}-r_{uv_x}^2c_{\Psi_u}
\end{array}
\right]
\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(You're missing several `\\` (double backslash) directives, at the end of each `array` environment as well as between rows 2 and 3 of the multi-line equation. Once that's fixed, you'll find that `split` and `array` environments are entirely compatible with each other.)

I suggest you use `bmatrix` ("matrix with square **b**rackets") environments instead of the "plain" `array` environments. The typeset result will be much more compact-looking, which is probably something you want.

The `amsmath` package provides the macro `\lVert` and `\rVert`; use them, rather than `||`. In the example code below, I set up a macro called `\norm` that makes use of `\lVert` and `\rVert`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % loads 'amsmath' automatically
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&{-}\frac{r_{uv}^\perp(r_{uv}^\perp)^T}{\norm{p_v-p_u}}\,T(\Psi_u)^T\\
&\qquad=
\frac{\begin{bmatrix}
r_{uv_y}^2 & -r_{uv_x}r_{uv_y}\\
-r_{uv_x}r_{uv_y} & r_{uv_x}^2
\end{bmatrix}}{\norm{p_v-p_u}}
\begin{bmatrix*}[r]
\cos(\Psi_u) & \sin(\Psi_u)\\
-\sin(\Psi_u)  &  \cos(\Psi_u)\\
\end{bmatrix*} \\
&\qquad=
\begin{bmatrix}
-r_{uv_y}^2c_{\Psi_u}-r_{uv_x}r_{uv_y}s_{\Psi_u} & r_{uv_y}^2s_{\Psi_u}+r_{uv_x}r_{uv_y}c_{\Psi_u}\\
r_{uv_x}r_{uv_y}c_{\Psi_u}+r_{uv_x}^2s_{\Psi_u} & r_{uv_x}r_{uv_y}s_{\Psi_u}-r_{uv_x}^2c_{\Psi_u}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It works perfectly thanks for the time you spent for me.